# How do you send emails from Angular controllers on the Mean.js stack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs, nodemailer

I'm using the [Mean.js](http://meanjs.org/) stack and I'm having issues figuring out how to send emails using the nodemailer package from inside an AngularJS controller. I have the following code:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Hello <hello@email.com>',
    to: 'email@gmail.com',
    subject: 'email subject',
    text: 'email body',
    html: 'html body'
};

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailer.options);
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        res.send({
            message: 'Email has been sent'
        });
    }

    done(err);
});
```

But I receive the error `ReferenceError: nodemailer is not defined`. I've tried injecting the dependency into the controller using:

```
angular.module('offers').controller('OffersController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Offers', 'nodemailer',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Offers, nodemailer) {
    ...
```

but I only get the error `Unknown provider: nodemailerProvider`. I've also added the dependency to app/config/express.js as so `nodemailer = require('nodemailer')`, but still no luck.

I see in the npm package nodemailer/src/nodemailer.js the following lines:

```
function Nodemailer(transporter) {
...
```

and

```
module.exports.createTransport = function(transporter)
...
```

so I would assume that I could access the package through a global Nodemailer object, as so: `Nodemailer.createTransport(...)`, but that is undefined as well.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your code, you cannot inject nodemailer in an angular controller because it is not a service or a provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Nodemailer have to run on server side.

Just trigger the sending with a `$http` request from angular.

You can find an example [here](http://www.bossable.com/1910/angularjs-nodemailer-contact-form/)

If you're getting a reference error please check that you've installed `nodemailer` correctly with `npm install nodemailer --save`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you cannot inject nodemailer in an angular controller because it is not a service or a provider.

You have 2 options:-

1. Assuming it is just available as a node package and you have already installed it, you can include the script in your html file from node_modules folder, and that way nodemailer will be available in your app as a global object. Personally, I won't use this approach, and take the 2nd approach.
2. This is the preferred option - Create an http endpoint on your node server which does the mailing bit using nodemailer. Then send an http request to the end point to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I think Nodemailer have to run on server side.

Just trigger the sending with a $http request from angular.

You can find an example here

If you're getting a reference error please check that you've installed nodemailer correctly with npm install nodemailer --save.